# ORMLite set an alias for column instead of table

Tags: android, orm, alias, ormlite

How can I add an alias *(AS)* when selecting columns? I want to achieve something like:

```
SELECT `foo` AS `bar` FROM `xyz` WHERE `abc` = '123' ORDER BY `bar`
```

I've tried using **setAlias** method right after my **selectColumns** but it sets the alias to the table, which I think is intended since it was mentioned in the [docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#setAlias(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a example of creating alias [check this](http://android.technoedu.com/forums/topic/android-sqlite-solved-ormlite-alias-in-rawquery/)

```
String qry = "SELECT `foo` AS `bar` FROM `xyz` WHERE `abc` = '123' ORDER BY `bar`";
GenericRawResults<Foo> rawResults =
    orderDao.queryRaw(qry, new RawRowMapper<Foo>() {
        public Foo mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) {
            // assuming 0th field is the foo
            return new Foo(resultColumns[0]));
        }
     });
// page through the results
for (Foo foo : rawResults) {
   Log.e("result data ", "::" + foo.name");
}
rawResults.close();
```

you can also go through [this doc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/J0QFZLcaHAs)

Comment: just a followup question, can this be used as subquery as well?

Comment: yes, you can use that in subqry and just need maintain **resultColumns** for what you want in result as well as check above link described@GamatheGreat